# $H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ norm is invariant under orthogonal maps?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, fractional-sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

How to prove that $H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ norm is invariant under  orthogonal maps? That IS, given $u \in H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ and $T \in O(N)$, How to obtain
$$
||u\circ T||_{H^{1}_0(\Omega)} = ||u||_{H^{1}_0(\Omega)} ?
$$

Comment: A small comment: Unless $T(\Omega) = \Omega$, you should have $\| u\|_{H^1(T(\Omega))}$ on the right hand side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed in two steps:

1)If $u$ is weakly differentiable, then the weak gradient of $u \circ T$ is given by $T^T \nabla u \circ T$.

2)Now use the fact that $T^TT=I$ and use a change of variable. Note that $|\det(T)|=1$.

Comment: Thank you F. Conrad. But, I think you meant that the weak gradient of $u \circ T$ is given by $T^T \nabla u \circ T$, right ?

Comment: Thanks edited it

Answer (score 0):

Use a change of variables and the fact that $\vert \text{det}\, T \vert = 1$.